# windows 8 password box not have password value property wpf User control

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls

I have created a usercontrol with button inside the passwordbox.

```
 <DockPanel Canvas.Right="2" Canvas.Top="2">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonWithoutHover}" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="15" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="->"  Click="onButtonClick" Grid.Column="1" >                   
                </Button>
                <PasswordBox BorderThickness="0" Name="txtPassword" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Grid.Column="0" />
            </DockPanel>
```

While Implementing The Password or Text or value property not found.

> txtPasswordBox.??????

What I miss in this project,.

My project [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2w9Ww9b3kRveXVfOVQwX0hielU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with Password property of Passowrd box,thanks for the sample link.

Code Snippet:

```
private void PasswordBoxWin8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var passwordBox = txtPasswordBox.FindName("txtPassword") as PasswordBox;
        MessageBox.Show(passwordBox.Password);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried, but txtPassword.Password / txtPassword.Value / txtPassword.text Nothing found in Usercontrol. I have upload my project in net and give the link also, try and tell me the solutions sir.

Comment: The link seems to be broken,can u please check it?

Comment: Sorry I have post this an article but its waiting for approval. You can download now in https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo&authuser=0#folders/0B2w9Ww9b3kRva1VITTAyTGdhYXM

Comment: pls see my edited code.you are accessing that usercontrol in MainWindow Right?

Comment: Thanks @Ravuthasanmy. Now I got IT. The Name Foreground property are there but this one has missing. Why its happening.

Comment: The Name,Foreground property are present in Control Class not in Passwordbox class.so they are present

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40633/discussion-between-ravuthasamy-and-sagotharan)